# Facebook (#100) App is not installed, when trying to remove a Page Tab Application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tabs

I get a "message: "(#100) App is not installed:" when i try to delete a pagetab application from a specific page using graph api.

Here are the steps to reporduce the problem.

1. Visit graph api explorer at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.0
2. Get an access token with manage pages permission and request me/accounts using GET method.
3. You will see list of pages you are admin / owner of. Copy an access token from the page you wish to delete a tab. And paste that access token at the top under the access token field.
4. Now click the id of the the page (from where u have copied the access token) and you will see page data as a result of api/2.0/pageId GET method. This data contains all the infomration of page tabs. If it works till this part. You can just add /tabs a the end of the above command to see the information of tabs. i.e. API/2.0/{PAGE_ID}/tabs
5. Now you will see a list of page tabs, click on the id of one of tabs that is added by you(Not the fixed ones like photos and like tab). The id should be in the form of API/2.0/{PAGE_ID}/tabs/app_{APP_ID}. And choose the DELETE method from the dropdown.

Now click the submit button and you will get Error 100.

I have spent quite much of the time in resolving this but its not working at all for me. Please try the above procedure and help me knowing if I am doing something wrong or is it a facebook bug. I did all the above steps according to the inromation provided under facebook documentation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/tabs

Comment: Sounds like a Facebook bug so if you haven't reported it you should on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Yes it was a bug, they fixed it :)

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/632836396808061/